# Why is Widgetlocker app evading my task-killer?

Tags: services, application-manager

The Widgetlocker app (a screen lock replacement app) has a service running which I can see in my app manager (under phone settings), but NOT in my task-killer app (Advanced Task Manager).  How is its service evading my task-killer?

I can stop its service in the phones app manager, which terminates the app. I dont have Widgetlocker set as my default home app, and I'm not including it in my task-killer "ignore" list. I did give it root permission to bypass its "5 second rule".

Comment: You really shouldn't run a task killer.

Answer (score 1):

if you go to Advanced Task Manager, you can set (in the settings) the security level to low, which will show you running services. By default it only shows processes.

Comment: I cant find that setting